# "object not found" error with CBCgrps package

Tags: r

I'm trying to check for baseline differences by a grouping variable in a survey data.

By running this code I get the error "object 'condition' not found". Why is that? I followed precisely the example here https://rdrr.io/cran/CBCgrps/man/twogrps.html

Quotes around the variables removed the error, but I got an empty table that does not show any results.

```
twogrps(df, condition, varlist = sum_variable, p.rd = 3, 
        skewvar=NULL, norm.rd = 2, 
        sk.rd = 2, tabNA = "no", cat.rd = 0, pnormtest = 0.05,
        maxfactorlevels = 30, minfactorlevels = 10, sim = FALSE, 
        workspace = 2e+05,ShowStatistic = F,ExtractP = 0.05)
```

Data

```
structure(list(condition = c(2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
2, 1), sum_variable = c(9, 6, 13, 3, 4, 3, 12, 2, 7, 8, 7, 4, 
5, 10, 2, 5, 4, NA, 14, 9, 2, 5, 7, 3, NA, 3, 5, 7, 3, 8, 3, 
3, 4, 8, 10, 9, 5, 7, 8, 4, 9, NA, 10, 14, 10, 3, 4, 10, 3, NA, 
5, 3, 4, 4, NA, 5, 4, 6, 6, 9, 6, 2, 3, NA, 4, NA, 2, 2, 6, 5, 
5, 3, 5, NA, 4, 4)), row.names = c(NA, -76L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

EDIT: edited according to the comments

Comment: In the examples you linked, the column names are passed as characters, not symbols. e.g., `"condition"`, not `condition`.

Comment: I tried that too. And it's true, with hyphens it doesn't produce an error message anymore, but either it produces any meaningful result

Comment: Did you also include them around `sum_variable`? If so, I suggest you [edit] your question with the corrected code, the result, and why the result isn't "meaningful" -- explain or show an example of what you expect the result to be.

Comment: And by the way, `"` are "quotes" or "quotation marks," not "hyphens"; this is a hyphen: `-`. :)